# Tokbox streamCreated being called same number of times client is called

Tags: javascript, webrtc, opentok, tokbox

I'm calling on a client, one-to-one, multiple times during a session and the `streamCreated` event gets called on the host.  When I hang up, I unsubscribe and the client unpublishes. However, when I call on the client again, the `streamCreated` event gets called twice on the host's side. I call on the client 3, 4, 5, etc. more times and the `streamCreated` event fires the same number of times as I have called on the client. For example on the 7th time I call the client, `streamCreated` gets called 7 times!  It seems like I'm not really destroying the streams although `streamDestroyed` gets called.

On the client side, I was desperate enough to try and unpublish with:

```
clientSession.unpublish(clientPublisher, handleError);
clientPublisher.stream.destroy();
clientPublisher.destroy();
clientPublisher = null;
```

On the host side, I've also tried to make sure the subscriber was destroyed:

```
clientSession.unsubscribe(clientSubscriber);
clientSubscriber.destroy();
clientSubscriber = null;
```

The problem with this is when I open a video monitor with multiple clients and have each client publish without audio.  However, I can still hear the client I called on... like their original stream(s) still exists.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: TokBox Developer Evangelist here. I understand that you found a solution, but I wanted to confirm that both streams are being destroyed when you "hang-up"? If you only unpublish one stream, the other stream may still be publishing unless you explicitly unpublish the other stream as well.

Comment: That is correct, I'm unpublishing both streams.  Thanks for checking.

Answer (score 2):

Every time I called on the person, I was using:

```
clientSession.on('streamCreated', function (event) {
clientSubscriber = clientSession.subscribe(event.stream, vid, {
...
```

So, each time I called on a client, it created a new event handler.  To correct the issue, I added the following code when I disconnected from the client.

```
clientSession.unsubscribe(clientSubscriber);
clientSession.off();
```

That killed the event handler and everything works properly now.