# #OpenTok how enumerate streams in a session?

Tags: opentok, tokbox

I'm subscribing to only one of many publishers, one at a time (video monitor).  So, I initially open all subscribers and when the onconnected event is fired, I store each of them in a hash table (stream.connection.data holds ID).  I subscribe to the first, then unsubscribe and subscribe to the next.  However, I've had to kill the onconnected event handler so they didn't keep firing multiple times:
[Tokbox streamCreated being called same number of times client is called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53394200/tokbox-streamcreated-being-called-same-number-of-times-client-is-called)

Now, when a new participant joins the session late (after the event handler has been removed) I don't know how to subscribe to their stream since no event fires.  I know they have connected and are streaming because I get a message from their application that contains the ID of their stream.

So, I need a way to iterate through all the steams in the session, find the new one, and subscribe to it when it's that person's turn.  How, can I get all the streams in a session and look at their connection ID's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TokBox Developer Evangelist here.

To know the number of streams in a session on the **client side**, I recommend listening to the following session events:

- `streamCreated` - fires when someone starts publishing in a session
- `streamDestroyed` - fires when someone stops publishing in a session.

I would create an object like below to keep a record of all streams in a session:

```
const streams = {};
session.on({
  streamCreated: event => {
    streams[event.stream.streamId] = event.stream;
  },
  streamDestroyed: event => {
    delete streams[event.stream.streamId];
  },
};
```

This would then allow you to access the stream object and subscribe like so:

```
const stream = streams['f39c6-ae02-100c-9727-b3bf2']; // please note that this is a random stream Id
const subscriber = session.subscribe(stream);
```

If you would like to know the number of streams in a session on the **server side**, you can use [Session Monitoring](https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/session-monitoring/) and listen to the same events.

Comment: I do keep track of them in a hash table based on the streamcreated event.  I was able to get this to work just due to an error in my code, but I would still like to know if there is a way to enumerate the streams in a session without first catching them in the event.

Comment: Currently, there is no public API that exposes the active streams in a session, you would have to keep track of the streams based on the events.