# OpenTok TokBox: How can I automatically start a live streaming (rtmp) broadcast of a session when the first connected user publishes?

Tags: opentok, tokbox

I've seen the sample app on github.  There is an explicit "Start Broadcasting" button that does what it sounds like (starts broadcasting rtmp).

I'd like not to have an explicit button.  I'd like to start broadcasting when the first user in a session publishes his or her camera.  So if 5 users connect to the session, call broadcast when the first of them publishes a stream, but not when any of the others do.

Can I query the session and know whether it is live streaming currently?  What is the best practice here?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TokBox Developer Evangelist here.

You cannot query the number of active streams in a [Session](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/Session.html), you would have to store that information on your own as events are being dispatched. Please see this SO answer for more details: [#OpenTok how enumerate streams in a session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53947066/opentok-how-enumerate-streams-in-a-session)

As for broadcasting, you can start broadcasting programmatically when the first person starts publishing instead of using a visual component to trigger the call. For example, on the client side, you can listen for the `streamCreated` event and then send a request to your application server to start the broadcast. Your application server would then have to make a the `startBroadcast` call to OpenTok via a [Server SDK](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/server/) or using the [REST API](https://tokbox.com/developer/rest/).

Alternatively, you could use [Session Monitoring](https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/session-monitoring/) to listen to [Stream](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/StreamEvent.html) and [Connection](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/ConnectionEvent.html) events on the server via a webhook, to  start the broadcast.

To find out more on how OpenTok Broadcasting works, I recommend checking out the following resources:

- [OpenTok Broadcasting Developer Guide](https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/broadcast/)
- [OpenTok Broadcasting Webinar](https://www.crowdcast.io/e/building-with-opentok-9)

Comment: Thank you for the info.